# Elements stacking in fixed top navbar bootstrap5

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am currently working on a website with a fixed top navbar. The website navbar looked like this:

[image: correct]

I was asked to place the logo of the site next to the side menu toggle item (those three stacked dashes to the left.

I did so by changing this code snippet:

```
<header class="header" id="header">

        <div class="header_toggle" id="toggle-up"> <i class="fas fa-bars secondary-bs-color" id="header-toggle"></i></div>

        <div id="nav-buttons" class="me-5 d-sm-block">
            <button type="button" class="white-bs-color fw-bold btn btn-primary me-4" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#login-modal">Login</button>
            <button type="button" class="white-bs-color fw-bold btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#registration-modal">Register</button>
        </div>

</header>
```

to this:

```
<header class="header" id="header">

        <div class="d-inline">
            <div class="header_toggle" id="toggle-up"> <i class="fas fa-bars secondary-bs-color" id="header-toggle"></i></div>
            <img class="w-5 h-auto" src="./img/Logo Vegaz Bet MOEDA.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div id="nav-buttons" class="me-5 d-sm-block">
            <button type="button" class="white-bs-color fw-bold btn btn-primary me-4" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#login-modal">Login</button>
            <button type="button" class="white-bs-color fw-bold btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#registration-modal">Register</button>
        </div>

</header>
```

Yet, after doint it, all elements in the top bar started to stack and I can't figure out why...

[image: incorrect]

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to fix it? Here is my full code (custom.css is the bootstrap library)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

    <link href="./css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./css/navlayout.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="./js/navlayout.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/js/all.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="icon" href="./img/icon.png" />

    <title>Vegaz.bet</title>
</head>

<body id="body-pd" style="background: url('./img/Home e Roleta.png') no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover;">
    <header class="top-header align-middle">
        <div class="mx-auto"></div>
    </header>
    <header class="header" id="header">

        <div class="header_toggle" id="toggle-up"> <i class="fas fa-bars secondary-bs-color" id="header-toggle"></i></div>

        <div id="nav-buttons" class="me-5 d-sm-block">
            <button type="button" class="white-bs-color fw-bold btn btn-primary me-4" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#login-modal">Login</button>
            <button type="button" class="white-bs-color fw-bold btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#registration-modal">Register</button>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="l-navbar" id="nav-bar">
        <nav class="nav">
            <div>
                <div class="nav_list">
                    <a href="#" class="nav_link active"> <i class="fas fa-chart-line nav_icon secondary-bs-color"></i> <span class="nav_name">Crash</span> </a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class="far fa-life-ring nav_icon secondary-bs-color"></i> <span class="nav_name">Roullete</span> </a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class="fas fa-dice nav_icon secondary-bs-color"></i> <span class="nav_name">Dice</span> </a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class="fas fa-coins nav_icon secondary-bs-color"></i> <span class="nav_name">Heads or Tails</span> </a>
                    <hr class="bg-white border-2 border-top border-white">
                    <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd nav_icon white-bs-color"></i> <span class="nav_name">Deposit /<br> Withdrawal</span> </a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class="far fa-question-circle nav_icon white-bs-color"></i> <span class="nav_name">Help</span> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="r-navbar invisible" id="nav-bar-chat">

        <div id="invisible-toggle-div" class="container pb-5 invisible">

            <div class="row h-20 mb-1">
                <button id="close-chat" type="button" class="position-absolute top-8 start-10 btn-close btn-close-white" aria-label="Close"></button>
                <button type="button" class="w-50 position-absolute top-7 end-10 white-bs-color fw-bold btn btn-primary"><span class="text-nowrap">Vegaz Chat</span></button>
            </div>

            <div class="row h-60">
                <div id="chatContainer" class="chat-font d-flex flex-column bd-highlight position-absolute top-15 end-5 w-90 h-75">
                    
                    <span class="time-span-chat ms-2">11:29</span>
                    <div class="card bg-field-grey text-white mb-1">
                        <span class="pt-1 pb-1 ps-1 pe-1"><span class="fw-bold" style="color: yellow">youranus420:</span> oi putões</span>
                    </div>
                    
                    <span class="time-span-chat ms-2">11:29</span>
                    <div class="card bg-field-grey text-white mb-1">
                        <span class="pt-1 pb-1 ps-1 pe-1"><span class="fw-bold" style="color: yellow">youranus420:</span> bora crash?</span>
                    </div>
                    
                    <span class="time-span-chat ms-2">11:30</span>
                    <div class="card bg-field-grey text-white mb-1">
                        <span class="pt-1 pb-1 ps-1 pe-1"><span class="fw-bold" style="color: purple">elon musk:</span> Olha o nome do cara kkkkk</span>
                    </div>
                        
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row h-10">
                <div class="bg-primary text-center position-absolute end-3 bottom-6 w-94 h-5">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="chat-font form-control" placeholder="Your message" aria-label="Message">
                        <button class="chat-font btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon2">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <!--Container Main start-->
    <div class="height-100">
        <h4>Main Components</h4>

        <a class="position-absolute bottom-5 end-5 float-icon-chat" id="chatButton" role="button">
            <span class="position-absolute top-15 start-20"><i class="far fa-comment-dots" style="font-size: 40px;"></i></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <!--Container Main end-->

    <!-- Login modal -->
    <div class="modal fade modal-fullscreen-sm-down" id="login-modal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog bg-primary">
            <div class="bg-primary text-white border border-4 border-secondary modal-content">
                <div class="border-bottom border-4 border-secondary modal-header">
                    <div class="mx-auto">
                        <button type="button" class="white-bs-color fw-bold btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                        <button type="button" class="white-bs-color fw-bold opacity-50 btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#registration-modal">Register</button>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="position-absolute end-5 btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight">
                        <div class="text-center p-2 bd-highlight">
                            <img src="" alt="Logo Vegaz">
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center fw-bold p-2 bd-highlight">
                            Login to Vegaz
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center p-2 bd-highlight">
                            <input class="bg-field-grey text-white border-0 form-control mb-3" type="text" placeholder="Username or Email" id="login-username" aria-label="Username">
                            <input class="bg-field-grey text-white border-0 form-control mb-3" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="login-password" aria-label="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center p-2 bd-highlight">
                            <button type="button" class="white-bs-color btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#recover-modal">Forgot your password?</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="border-top border-4 border-secondary modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="mx-auto btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Recover password modal -->
    <div class="modal fade modal-fullscreen-sm-down" id="recover-modal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog bg-primary">
            <div class="bg-primary text-white border border-4 border-secondary modal-content">
                <div class="border-bottom border-4 border-secondary modal-header">
                    <div class="mx-auto">
                        <button type="button" class="white-bs-color fw-bold btn btn-primary">Recover your password</button>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="position-absolute end-5 btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
                        <div class="text-center p-2 bd-highlight">
                            <img src="" alt="Logo Vegaz">
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center fw-bold p-2 bd-highlight">
                            We'll send you an email with instructions to recover your account
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center p-2 bd-highlight">
                            <input class="bg-field-grey text-white border-0 form-control mb-3" type="email" placeholder="Email" id="recover-email" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="border-top border-4 border-secondary modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="mx-auto btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#recover-confirmation-modal">Recover password</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Recover password confirmation modal -->
    <div class="modal fade modal-fullscreen-sm-down" id="recover-confirmation-modal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog bg-primary">
            <div class="bg-primary text-white border border-4 border-secondary modal-content">
                <div class="border-bottom border-4 border-secondary modal-header">
                    <div class="mx-auto text-center fw-bold">
                        Recover your password
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="position-absolute end-5 btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
                        <div class="text-center p-2 bd-highlight">
                            <img src="" alt="Logo Vegaz">
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center p-2 bd-highlight">
                            You'll receive an email shortly with instructions to recover your password. Check your inbox!
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="border-top border-4 border-secondary modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="mx-auto btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Understood</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Registration modal -->
    <div class="modal fade modal-fullscreen-sm-down" id="registration-modal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog bg-primary">
            <div class="bg-primary text-white border border-4 border-secondary modal-content">
                <div class="border-bottom border-4 border-secondary modal-header">
                    <div class="mx-auto">
                        <button type="button" class="white-bs-color fw-bold opacity-50 btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#login-modal">Login</button>
                        <button type="button" class="white-bs-color fw-bold btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="position-absolute end-5 btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
                        <div class="text-center p-2 bd-highlight">
                            <img src="" alt="Logo Vegaz">
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center fw-bold p-2 bd-highlight">
                            Create your Vegaz account
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center p-2 bd-highlight">
                            <input class="bg-field-grey text-white border-0 form-control mb-3" type="email"  placeholder="Email" id="register-email" >
                            <input class="bg-field-grey text-white border-0 form-control mb-3" type="text" placeholder="Username" id="register-username" aria-label="Username">
                            <input class="bg-field-grey text-white border-0 form-control mb-3" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="register-password" aria-label="Password">
                            <input class="bg-field-grey text-white border-0 form-control mb-3" type="password" placeholder="Password repeat" id="register-password-repeat" aria-label="Password repeat">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="border-top border-4 border-secondary modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="mx-auto btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#registration-confirmation-modal">Register</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Registration confirmation modal -->
    <div class="modal fade modal-fullscreen-sm-down" id="registration-confirmation-modal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog bg-primary">
            <div class="bg-primary text-white border border-4 border-secondary modal-content">
                <div class="border-bottom border-4 border-secondary modal-header">
                    <div class="mx-auto text-center fw-bold">
                        Welcome to Vegaz
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="position-absolute end-5 btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
                        <div class="text-center p-2 bd-highlight">
                            <img src="" alt="Logo Vegaz">
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center p-2 bd-highlight">
                            You're now part of the best online gaming casino community!
                            Let's play and good luck!
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="border-top border-4 border-secondary modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="mx-auto btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Start playing!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap");
:root {
    --top-header-top-position: 5%;
    --header-height: 3rem;
    --nav-width: 68px;
    --chat-width: 100px;
    --primary-color: var(--bs-primary);
    --secondary-color: var(--bs-secondary);
    --white-color: var(--bs-white);
    --body-font: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    --normal-font-size: 1rem;
    --z-fixed: 100;
    --z-topbar: 101;
}

*,
::before,
::after {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.top-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: var(--top-header-top-position);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    z-index: var(--z-topbar);
    transition: .5s;
    text-align: center !important;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: var(--header-height);
    position: fixed;
    top: var(--top-header-top-position);
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    z-index: var(--z-fixed);
    transition: .5s
}

.header_toggle {
    color: var(--primary-color);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer
}

.header_img {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden
}

.header_img img {
    width: 40px
}

.l-navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -30%;
    width: var(--nav-width);
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    padding: .5rem 1rem 0 0;
    transition: .5s;
    z-index: var(--z-fixed)
}

.r-navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    padding: 1rem 0 0 1rem;
    transition: .5s;
    z-index: var(--z-fixed);
    padding: 1rem 0 0 1rem;
}

.nav {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 5rem;
}

.nav_logo,
.nav_link {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: 1rem;
    padding: .5rem 0 .5rem 1.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav_logo {
    margin-bottom: 2rem
}

.nav_logo-icon {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    color: var(--white-color)
}

.nav_logo-name {
    color: var(--white-color);
    font-weight: 700
}

.nav_link {
    position: relative;
    color: var(--white-color);
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    transition: .3s
}

.nav_link:hover {
    color: var(--white-color)
}

.nav_icon {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.secondary-bs-color {
    color: var(--bs-secondary)
}

.white-bs-color {
    color: var(--white-color)
}

.show-left-nav {
    left: 0;
    width: calc(var(--nav-width) + 156px);
}

.show-right-nav {
    width: 100%;
}

.body-menu-pd {
    padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 188px); 
}

.body-chat-pd {
    padding-right: calc(var(--chat-width) + 1rem);
}

.chat-font {
    font-size: small;
}

.time-span-chat {
    font-size: smaller;
    color: var(--white-color);
}

#chatContainer {
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* for Internet Explorer, Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none; /* for Firefox */
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}

#chatContainer::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none; /* for Chrome, Safari, and Opera */
}

.active {
    color: var(--white-color)
}

.active::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: var(--white-color)
}

.height-100 {
    height: 100vh
}

.float-icon-chat {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 40px;
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    color: var(--white-color);
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .header {
        height: calc(var(--header-height) + 1rem);
        padding: 0 2rem 0 calc(var(--nav-width) + 2rem)
    }
    .header_img {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px
    }
    .header_img img {
        width: 45px
    }
    .l-navbar {
        left: 0;
        padding: 1rem 1rem 0 0
    }
    .r-navbar {
        right: 0;
        padding: 1rem 0 0 1rem;
        width: 0;
    }
    .show-left-nav {
        width: calc(var(--nav-width) + 156px)
    }
    .show-right-nav {
        width: calc(var(--chat-width) + 156px)
    }
    .body-menu-pd {
        padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 188px);   
    }
    .body-chat-pd {
        padding-right: calc(var(--chat-width) + 156px)
    }
}
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    const showNavbar = (toggleId, navId, bodyId, headerId) => {
        const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
            nav = document.getElementById(navId),
            bodypd = document.getElementById(bodyId),
            headerpd = document.getElementById(headerId),
            toggleup = document.getElementById("toggle-up")

        // Validate that all variables exist
        if (toggle && nav && bodypd && headerpd) {
            toggleup.addEventListener('click', () => {
                // show navbar
                nav.classList.toggle('show-left-nav');
                //hide navbar buttons on sm
                document.getElementById("nav-buttons").classList.toggle('d-none');
                // change icon
                toggle.classList.toggle('fa-times');
                // add padding to body
                bodypd.classList.toggle('body-menu-pd');
                // add padding to header
                headerpd.classList.toggle('body-menu-pd');
            });
        }
        
    }

    showNavbar('header-toggle', 'nav-bar', 'body-pd', 'header');


    /*===== LINK ACTIVE =====*/
    const linkColor = document.querySelectorAll('.nav_link');

    function colorLink() {
        if (linkColor) {
            linkColor.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active'));
            this.classList.add('active');
        }
    }
    linkColor.forEach(l => l.addEventListener('click', colorLink));

    // show chat
    const showChat = (toggleId, navId, bodyId, headerId) => {
        const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
            nav = document.getElementById(navId),
            bodypd = document.getElementById(bodyId),
            headerpd = document.getElementById(headerId),
            closeChat = document.getElementById("close-chat")

        // Validate that all variables exist
        if (toggle && nav && bodypd && headerpd) {
            const toggleFunc = () => {
                // show navbar
                document.getElementById("invisible-toggle-div").classList.toggle('invisible');
                nav.classList.toggle('invisible');
                nav.classList.toggle('show-right-nav');
                
                // change icon
                toggle.classList.toggle('invisible');
                // add padding to body
                bodypd.classList.toggle('body-chat-pd');
                // add padding to header
                headerpd.classList.toggle('body-chat-pd');
            }
            toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleFunc);
            closeChat.addEventListener('click', toggleFunc);
        }
        
    }

    showChat('chatButton', 'nav-bar-chat', 'body-pd', 'header');
    
});
```

Comment: have you tried d-flex instead of d-inline

Comment: An now I feel stupid kkkkk thanks it worked out. Would it be possible for you to elaborate on why this is the solution in an answer? I believe it would be very helpful for me (frontend newbie) and other that have the same problem

Comment: inline means that the element is displayed inline, inside the current block on the same line. Only when it's between two blocks does the element form an 'anonymous block', that however has the smallest possible width. display flex is just like putting elements in a row